# print command inside while loop not getting executed (python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, printing, series

```
n=1
while n>=40:
    print(n)
    n+=3
```

**The objective is to print a series 1,4,7....40**

for the above result when execute python doesn't give any output. [code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJxdE.png)

Answer (score 1):

`n` is not bigger or equal than 40, so the loop doesn't run. I think you meant `<=` instead of `>=`